# Postgres LAST_VALUE returns not the last value when using where clause in main query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to understand windowing functions in Postgres
and I don't get it.
Here's an example. Just trying to get the last value of an record set restricted with where clause:

```
 tid | pid | position |      recorded       | uvalue | cvalue | record_id 
-----+-----+----------+---------------------+--------+--------+-----------
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2022-02-01 12:00:00 |    270 |    270 |       102
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2022-03-15 12:00:00 |    270 |    254 |       102
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2022-11-17 12:00:00 |    270 |        |       102
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2022-12-01 14:00:00 |    270 |        |       102
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2023-02-03 11:00:00 |    270 |        |       102
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2023-03-01 04:00:00 |    270 |        |       102
  10 |   2 |      100 | 2023-04-01 04:00:00 |    270 |    251 |       102
```

And this the query

```
select last_value(cvalue) over (order by recorded) 
from data 
where recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00';
```

results in

```
 last_value 
------------
        270
        254
(2 rows)
```

It should be 254?

Comment: could you create a db fiddle? https://dbfiddle.uk

Comment: window functions are executed for each row. Each row has a window and your query returns last value for that rows window.

Answer (score 2):

The window functions calculate one result for each row selected by the `WHERE` clause.

In your example there are two rows where `recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00'` so it is normal that you get two rows in the final result.

Then the window is calculated for each row by the `OVER()` clause which is by default equivalent to `OVER(ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. So it is again normal that you get `270` and `254` for both resulting rows aligned with the `over (order by recorded)` clause of your query.

You should read carefully the manual [§3.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) and [§4.2.8](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

If you only want one resulting row then you can do :

```
select cvalue
  from data 
 where recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00'
 order by recorded DESC
 limit 1
```

or you can use an aggregate function :

```
select (array_agg(cvalue ORDER BY recorded DESC))[1]
  from data 
 where recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00'
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b3034b19b191bf3a71d201d9db556329)

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented behaviour

> Note that first_value, last_value, and nth_value consider only the
> rows within the “window frame”, which by default contains the rows
> from the start of the partition through the last peer of the current row

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-window.html

If you want the other frame specify it explicitly, for example

```
with cte as (
    select last_value(cvalue) over (order by recorded
       rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as lv
    from data
)
select *
from cte
where recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `last_value` window function will return the latest value each row after `where`

In your case, it will be suitable to use `first_value` window function with `order by recorded desc` that might return the latest `cvalue` by your condition.

```
select first_value(cvalue) over (order by recorded desc)
from t
where recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00'
```

Answer (score -1):

So what you where looking for is:

```
select 
   cvalue 
from 
   data 
where 
   recorded < '2022-11-17 12:00:00'
order by 
   recorded desc
limit 
   1
;
```