# group minute bars into 15 minute bars

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with minute bars and I want to create a view for 15 minute bars going from :00 to :15 to :30 etc..

Here is what my minute table looks like:

[image]

I need the open to be the first price in the 15 minute interval, high to be the highest, low the lowest and close the last price right before the end of the 15 minute interval and the volume to be the sum of the volumes in the interval.

I cannot figure out how to make that view.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

With [`date_bin`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-BIN), Postgres has the perfect tool to use for such grouping. Then just call the respective aggregation function:

```
SELECT
   date_bin('15 minutes', start_date, '2023-01-01') AS interval_start,
   FIRST_VALUE(open) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS open,
   MAX(high) AS highest,
   MIN(low) AS lowest,
   LAST_VALUE(close) OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS close
FROM the_table
GROUP BY date_bin('15 minutes', start_date, '2023-01-01');
```

(ok, close enough, see [Using GROUP BY with FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41840829/1048572) or [Postgres LAST_VALUE returns not the last value when using where clause in main query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71394185/1048572))